# How can I store the order of items in Ajax list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model

I have 2 models, users and projects. Right now, they are connected by has_and_belongs_to_many connection(many to many). User has a list of projects, and this list is sortable by ajax. But I want to store this order. How can I send this order and store in proper way?

Answer (score 1):

To sorteable list I work with jQueryUI -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

To get the list:

```
var projects = Array();
var j=0;

$("#sortable li").each(function(i, item){
   projects[j] = $("#"+item.id).html();            
   j++;
});

var data = {"list": projects};
```

Then I send data with ajax

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of the order of the projects on the user list as an attribute of the relationship between the users and the projects. Each pair of user/project has one attribute 'order', right?

So that information should go in the intermediary table (projects_users).

But since you cannot add attributes to a have_and_belongs_to_many link table you should change it to something like:

```
class User
  has_many :allocations
  has_many :projects, :through => :allocations
end

class Project
  has_many :allocations
  has_many :users, :through => :allocations
end
```

and the migration for the allocations table should be something like this:

```
create_table :allocations do |t|
  t.integer :project_id
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :order
end
```

That way, for each project a given user is allocated to you can specify the order.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The table should have an ID right? I thought you only use :id => false when creating a HABTM table.

Comment: How can i do ajax order saving ?

Comment: Oguz, Ajax is just a method of communication from the browser to the server. Ajax itself doesn't save or order anything. If you mean saving and ordering a list with javascript i think Manu Mora's solution is a good way to go. Sorry if i missundestood you.

Comment: RobinBrouwer, you are right. I mixed it a little bit. I will fix the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is loop through all the items with Javascript and send an Array of ID's to a Rails action using AJAX (like the example Manu Mora gave). The parameters would look something like this:

```
project_ids: 1,3,5,2,4
id: 1
```

Then in your Controller action you could do the following:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.update_attributes(:project_ids => params[:project_ids].split(","))
```

I don't know how to send the parameters in a way that it's an Array automatically, so I use `split`. I don't know if the order will be okay when using HABTM. If not, you should use `has_many :through` with an 'order' or 'position' column. The way I showed you wouldn't work then, because you also need to set the order column.

Hope it works. :)